# Customize lint warnings for deprecation/newapi

Tags: android, android-studio, backwards-compatibility, android-lint

i just wanna know if there is the possibility to customize the lint checks for the following case:

```
Spannable text;
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODE.N) {
text = Html.fromHtml(htmlString, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY, null, null);
} else {
text = Html.fromHtml(htmlString, null, null);
}
```

Without the if, the `Html.fromHtml(<4 params>)` would be indicated as error because it is not available below api 24 but thanks of the if condition the error indication is automatically suppresses.
The same thing does not happen for the deprecation warning about the `Html.fromHtml(<3 params>)` method. Since that method (thanks to the if) is executed only in the case it is not deprecated, this warning is wrong. I have to manually suppress it.

*There is the possibility to **teach** the Lint to automatically suppress the deprecation warning in this case???*

Second question, but linked:
*If i change the previous code in the following mode, the lint continue to indicate as error the "newApi method".
There is the possibility to handle it automatically?*
Thanks:

```
Spannable text = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODE.N
? Html.fromHtml(htmlString, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY, null, null)
: Html.fromHtml(htmlString, null, null);
```

Gianni

Comment: Have you tried annotation @SuppressLint("NewApi")?

Comment: Yes i did and it works.
What i am asking is a way to teach once for ever the Lint to automatically handle this situation without adding SuppressWarning every time!

Answer (score 1):

In current version of Android Studio it won't warn about that with `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODE.N)` surrounding your code. Seems that the Android Studio team has fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable Inspection from settings in Android studio. *Go to* **File >> Settings >> Editor >> Inspections** and uncheck **Calling new methods on older versions** or you can change severity to something else other that *Error*.

[image]

There are few other way also like **Configure the lint file**, **Configure lint options with Gradle** and few more [check here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html#gradle).

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't help me.
Following your answer i only can disable or change severity for ALL "Calling new methods on older versions" events. 
I just want to disable for the events handled with the check on sdk version.

however, thank you for your help!!

Comment: Ok....have you tried other options in provided link like Configure lint options with Gradle etc?

Comment: yes, but it just does the same of the window above. suppress every instance of that event. it is not what i'm looking for.